# Django apache internal server error

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I got "500 Internal Server Error", when I try to connect to my django project.

I try lots of way to setting the configuration file, include some method on stackoverflow. But I still can't solve the problem.Can someone help? Thank you very much.

This is my vhost wsgi config

```
<Directory "/home/antus/bazoo/Antus_Bazoo_Web">
  <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess antus_bazoo python- 
path=/home/antus/bazoo:/home/antus/bazoo/bazoo_env/lib/python3.7/site- 
packages display-name=antus_bazoo python-home=/home/antus/bazoo/bazoo_env
WSGIProcessGroup antus_bazoo
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/antus/bazoo/Antus_Bazoo_Web/wsgi.py process- 
group=antus_bazoo
```

This is the wsgi file

```
import os
import sys
import site

# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('/home/antus/bazoo/bazoo_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages')

# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/home/antus/bazoo')
sys.path.append('/home/antus/bazoo/Antus_Bazoo_Web')
sys.path.append('/home/antus/bazoo/antus_bazoo')

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Antus_Bazoo_Web.settings")

fh = open('/home/antus/bazoo/wsgi_hello.txt', 'w')
fh.write('wsgi execution')
fh.close()

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I do also save the errors in error log but it does not have anything to consider and even the file is not created.

- UPDATE

This is the Vhost configuration.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mywebsite
        ServerAlias www.mywebsite
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mywebsite
        DocumentRoot /home/antus/public_html
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/antus/public_html/cgi-bin/

        # Custom settings are loaded below this line (if any exist)
        Include /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/antus/bazoo/*.conf


        ErrorLog /usr/local/apache/logs/userdata/antus/bazoo/error_log
        CustomLog /usr/local/apache/logs/userdata/antus/bazoo/custom_log combined

        <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
                UserDir disabled
                UserDir enabled antus
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
                SuexecUserGroup antus antus
        </IfModule>

        <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
                suPHP_UserGroup antus antus
                suPHP_ConfigPath /home/antus
        </IfModule>

        <Directory "/home/antus/public_html">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you at least add your log file , we can't help you this way. It could be a million reasons.Also add more information about your virtualenv, your python and django version etc ..

Comment: If the log file isn't created, just open your settings.py and enable debugging ! Then, you wont see the 500 error, you'll see the error stack

Comment: Are you sure your Apache user has the rights to read and write in /home/antus?

Comment: @InesTlili Debugging is enabled but still nothing.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have added the apache to my user group.

Comment: @R.Namakin that is not possible, actually

Answer (score 0):

The "**500 Internal Server Error**" would indicate something has gone wrong on the server and seeing that the wsgi.py has a file open operation, I'd looking for errors start there seeing as well that you mentioned something about "**the file is not created**".

```
fh = open('/home/antus/bazoo/wsgi_hello.txt', 'w')
```

The above line will not create a file. To create a file with open() use:

```
fh = open('/home/antus/bazoo/wsgi_hello.txt', 'w+')
```

Also a bit of the logs would go a great way in debugging this